# How many ways can the students be selected if they can serve on both committees?

Tags: combinatorics

Question: There are 10 students. Four are needed for a committee A and three are needed for committee B. How many ways can the students be selected if they can serve on both committees?

Textbook's answer: 25,200.

My approach:

Selecting 4 students out of 10

$\binom{10}{4}$ = 210

Arranging the four students into the committee A:

$4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1$ = 24

Selecting three students out of those 4 and arranging them:

$\binom{4}{3}$ * 3! = 24

Answer: 210 * 24 * 24 = 120,960

---

My logic might be wrong, so if you could provide me a correct approach, then it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the students can be on either or both committees, we choose members *independently* for both committees from $10$ students.

Choice for first committee = $10 \choose 4$
Choice for second committee = $10 \choose 3$

So total number of combinations for two committees = ${10 \choose 4}{10 \choose 3} = 25200$

Please note there is no way to arrange students in a committee unless there is more information, such as there are specific roles within the committee that selected members play.

Comment: Thanks, now it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is $25\,200$, because that's $\binom{10}4\binom{10}3$.

You seem to have aimed at the situation in which all students from committee $B$ also belong to committee $A$.

Comment: Hello, thank you.